# How do I make a cheese, sausage, cracker spread?

Tags: cheese, sausages

I'm not sure what types of cheeses, crackers, sausages are needed for a holiday spread. What types of cheeses and sausages are acceptable use for this type of thing? What will give me a decent variety? Would it be better to have a cheese spread instead of the traditional sliced cheese?

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, the kind of sausage you want is called a summer sausage. There are many varieties as the term really just refers to a sausage that doesn't need to be refrigerated. You might be able to find a few different kinds to give you some variety.

As for cheeses, you can sort of go with whatever you'd like. Generally with sausage you'll see stuff like jack, cheddar, havarti or swiss. With crackers you might see a cheeseball which is usually a blend of cream cheese and a cheese like cheddar.

Comment: Any cured meat works, of course summer sausage being the most traditional.  Check this site out for alternative meats: http://www.projo.com/food/content/fd-fortuna_sausage_04-08-09_B0DT615_v18.205cb1e.html.  I tend to go with a medium sharp to sharp cheese, especially when making a cheese ball (which are awesome and easy).  I also have a tendancy to mix in some bacon bits and roll the cheeseball in bacon bits too (not the stuff in the bottle, but actual bacon crushed up).